# Embedded Devices Firewall and Soap

Tags: soap, embedded, firewall

hi i whas just wondering is it possible to have a embeded device running a webservice that we can call without opening extra ports on a standard firewall.
i think probably not. but still i wonder is it possible?
so for example can i program a webservie on an embeded consumer product with an internet connection and expect it to work without sending an installer to fiddle with his security.

and if not how does a remote desktop work ?

im all new to security so excuse my maby dumb questions.

Answer (score 0):

- ok i so i guess remote desktop will work with ssh.
  well i could poll a sql server for messages i guess, but thats not very elegant.
  anybody has a better idea for how to communicate vica verca with an embeded device without fidling with firewall of customer ??

please let me know, all ideas are welcome